# Why does this \regex_split:nnN results in error and insertion of `{`?

Tags: errors, expl3, latex3, l3regex

I am playing around with `expl3` and wanted to try some higher order programming.
In this example I define an environment and then perform an action on this environment:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}

\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\prop_new:N \l_files_prop
\newcommand{\addConfig}[2]{
    \prop_put:Nnn \l_files_prop {#1} {{#2}}
}
\newcommand{\printConfig}[2]{
    \prop_get:NnN \l_files_prop {#1} \l__files
    \cs_generate_variant:Nn {\regex_split:nnN} {nVN}
    \regex_split:nVN {;} {\l__files} {\l__files_split_tl}
    %\seq_set_split:NnV \l__files_split_tl {o} {\l__files}
  
    %\seq_set_split:Nnn \l__cmd_tl {\textbackslash} {\tl_to_str:n #2}
    \seq_map_inline:Nn \l__files_split_tl {
        \use:c {\cs_to_str:N #2} {##1}\\
    } 
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\addConfig{config1}{hello; world}
\addConfig{config2}{bye; world}
\addConfig{config3}{testFile.tex; testFile2.tex}

\noindent
\printConfig{config1}{\textit}
\printConfig{config2}{\textbf}
%\printConfig{config3}{\input}

\end{document}
```

which correctly results in

[image: result1]

however, I get the following error along with the correct output:

```
! LaTeX3 Error: Missing brace inserted when splitting or extracting
(LaTeX3)        submatches.

For immediate help type H <return>.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.75 \printConfig{config1}{\textit}
                                   

LaTeX was asked to do some regular expression operation, and the resulting
token list would not have the same number of begin-group and end-group tokens.
Braces were inserted: 1 left, 1 right.
```

and I don't really understand why;
I try to follow [this guide](https://www.alanshawn.com/tech/2020/10/04/latex3-tutorial.html) and work with [the documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/l3kernel/interface3.pdf) but I also couldn't find any information why this is occurring.

How can I rewrite the code to remove this error? And (more importantly), why does it appear?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are adding a spurious set of braces in your `\prop_put:Nnn` command:

```
\prop_put:Nnn \l_files_prop {#1} {{#2}}
```

Changing that to

```
\prop_put:Nnn \l_files_prop {#1} {#2}
```

solves the problem.  The error happens because with a token list `{hello;world}`, splitting it at the `;` will leave unbalanced braces in each item (`{hello` and `world}`), which is illegal, so `l3regex` inserts some to balance the token lists.

I also changed some things to conform better with `expl3` standards:

- All variables should be declared, so you need a `\tl_new:N \l__files_split_tl` and a `\tl_new:N \l__files` (see next item about this one);
- Variables should be named `\⟨scope⟩_⟨module⟩_⟨name⟩_⟨type⟩`
  so `\l__files` is a terrible name.  Something like `\l__fabian_files_tl` is better, assuming `fabian` is the module;
- `\cs_generate_variant:Nn` can be done only once per variant, so you can move it outside the command;
- Assuming `#2` is a control sequence, `\use:c {\cs_to_str:N #2}` has the same effect as just `#2`, so you can simplify;
- The output of `\regex_split:nnN` is a `seq` variable, not a `tl`, so you should use that instead;
- *[bonus]* If you just want to split at a `;` you don't need `regex` at all.  Instead of the `\regex_split:nVN` line you can use `\seq_set_split:NnV \l__fabian_files_split_seq { ; } \l__fabian_files_tl` (the main difference is that `\regex_split:nVN` will preserve spaces around items, but `\seq_set_split:NnV` will trim spaces).

Here's the code:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}

\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\prop_new:N \l_fabian_files_prop
\tl_new:N \l__fabian_files_tl
\seq_new:N \l__fabian_files_split_seq
% \cs_generate_variant:Nn \regex_split:nnN { nV }

\NewDocumentCommand \addConfig { mm }
  { \prop_put:Nnn \l_fabian_files_prop {#1} {#2} }
\NewDocumentCommand \printConfig { mm }
  {
    \prop_get:NnN \l_fabian_files_prop {#1} \l__fabian_files_tl
    % \regex_split:nVN { ; } \l__fabian_files_tl \l__fabian_files_split_seq
    \seq_set_split:NnV \l__fabian_files_split_seq { ; } \l__fabian_files_tl
    \seq_map_inline:Nn \l__fabian_files_split_seq { #2 {##1} \\ }
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\addConfig{config1}{hello; world}
\addConfig{config2}{bye; world}
\addConfig{config3}{testFile.tex; testFile2.tex}

\noindent
\printConfig{config1}{\textit}
\printConfig{config2}{\textbf}
%\printConfig{config3}{\input}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I'd prefer `\seq_set_split:NnV`, as it also trims white spaces, which is more likely what the OP wants.

Comment: i did use that first in a similar fashion but it wouldn't split in ; for some reason;

Comment: @FabianSchneider The main problem was `{{#2}}` in the definition of `\addConfig`. You don't want the additional braces.

Comment: 'Assuming #2 is a control sequence, \use:c {\cs_to_str:N #2} has the same effect as just #2, so you can simplify;'   i cant do that because textbf needs braces around the text that sould be displayed oterwise it just boldens the first character; when i trdted it at least

Comment: @FabianSchneider `\seq_set_split:NnV` is not so "smart" as `\regex_split:nVN`, so it won't peek inside braces (for example `hello;be{auti;ful};world` would be split as `hello`, `be{auti;ful}`, and `world`, and the `;` inside braces would not be seen.

Comment: @egreg I did mention that in the answer :)

Comment: great explanation and help thx :)

Comment: @FabianSchneider With `#2 { ##1 }` you have the braces around the argument to `\textbf`. Where's the problem? Doing `\use:c { \cs_to_str:N \textbf }` is a long journey just to produce `\textbf`.

Comment: @FabianSchneider Regarding `\use:c {\cs_to_str:N #2}`: If `#2` is `\textbf`, `\cs_to_str:N #2` will be `textbf`, and `\use:c {textbf}` will be `\textbf` again, with just more work.  The braces you _do_ need are the ones around `{##1}` (as egreg just said above; he is fast :)

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik By the way, the names I have in my code are exactly the same as you chose. `;-)`

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik is there any reason to use `xparse`s `\NewDocumentCommand` instead of just `\newcommand`? is `\newcommand` considered bad practice since `xparse` came along?

Comment: @FabianSchneider In this case no, no mandatory reason, you could have used `\newcommand` normally (although for example `\edef\x{\addConfig{config1}{hello; world}}` will break if defined with `\newcommand`).  But nowadays `\NewDocumentCommand` is part of the LaTeX kernel, so if you have an up-to-date distribution, it doesn't even require `xparse`, so in this case there is no reason _not_ to use it